# How to connect to RDS Instance in private subnet via NAT instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I realize the normal way to do this is use a Bastion Host or a VPN, but I (my boss) would like to know how to connect to a RDS instance in a private subnet via a public NAT instance.

I have a NAT instance with EIP, and wide open inbound rules

I have 2 private subnets with traffic defaulting via the NAT

The DB Security group is set to allow traffic from the NAT SG

I don't know what I'm missing - any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to setup a bastion client on the public subnet and then login to that first. Then, once connected to the bastion client, you'll be able to access the RDS instance.

alternatively, you could setup a VPN (check out OpenVPN) in the public subnet, then once you've established a VPN connection, you'll be able to connect to the RDS instance using the private IP.

You can't initiate connection from the outside internet to a private subnet.